# Splicemachine ERROR 08006 insufficient data

Tags: splice-machine

I've just managed to install Splicemachine on Centos and I try to run one of their demos (https://doc.splicemachine.com/onprem_install_demodata.html). But when running the loadsql.sql I have encountered this problem:

```
call SYSCS_UTIL.IMPORT_DATA('SPLICE' , 'T_HEADER'  , null , '/vagrant/splicemachine/demodata/data/theader.csv'   , ',' , null , null , 'yyyy-MM-dd' , null , 0 , null , null , null);
ERROR 08006: Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.
```

I'm running this on the standalone community version. What could be the issue?

Regards

EDIT:
New error today running the same script:

```
ERROR 08006: A network protocol error was encountered and the connection has been terminated: the requested command encountered an unarchitected and implementation-specific condition for which there was no architected message (additional information may be available in the derby.log file on the server)
ERROR 08006: DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: 08006, SQLERRMC: A communications error has been detected: {0}.::SQLSTATE: XJ001Java exception: 'Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.: org.apache.spark.SparkException'.
```

**Splice.log**

```
07:33:53,246 (RS:0;localhost:33863) WARN  [c.s.d.l.ManagerLoader] - No Manager implementation found.
07:48:49,850 (olap-worker-0) WARN  [c.s.d.i.SpliceSpark] - ##############################################################################
07:48:49,854 (olap-worker-0) WARN  [c.s.d.i.SpliceSpark] -     Initializing Spark with: master = yarn-client
07:48:49,854 (olap-worker-0) WARN  [c.s.d.i.SpliceSpark] - ##############################################################################
07:48:59,524 (olap-worker-0) WARN  [c.s.d.i.SpliceSpark] - Trying to get local hostname. This could be problem for host with multiple interfaces.
07:48:59,541 (olap-worker-0) WARN  [c.s.d.i.SpliceSpark] - For machine with multiple interfaces, please set hbase.master.hostname.

07:37:05,793 (pool-13-thread-1) ERROR [c.s.p.SnappyPipelineCompressor] - No Native Snappy Installed: Splice Machine's Write Pipeline will not compress data over the wire.
07:51:17,005 (olap-worker-0) ERROR [o.a.s.SparkContext] - Error initializing SparkContext.
07:51:19,803 (olap-worker-0) ERROR [o.a.s.u.Utils] - Uncaught exception in thread olap-worker-0
07:51:19,900 (olap-worker-0) ERROR [c.s.o.OlapRequestHandler] - Uncaught exception
07:51:21,662 (olapClientWorker-1) ERROR [c.s.s.StreamListener] - StreamListener failed
```

**yarn.log**

```
PM com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter setPipeline
WARNING: Multiple Servlet injectors detected. This is a warning indicating that you have more than one GuiceFilter running in your web application. If this is deliberate, you may safely ignore this message. If this is NOT deliberate however, your application may not work as expected.
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack from log/splice.log?  The Spark stack that performs the import has a Snappy component and we have seen in certain circumstances that can be problematic.

Comment: I edited the OP and added parts of the log where I found errors and warnings.

Comment: Thanks.  The new error means the mini yarn cluster could not launch the spark application used for the import.  Can you take a look at the yarn.log in the same directory as the splice.log?

Comment: I see. I've added the message I found in the yarn log. Thank you for your continuing assistance!